# MOSFET device selection for LED dimming

Tags: mosfet

I am thinking of developing a controller that can adjust the brightness of 12 V, 50 A, and 600 W LED.

> - **MOSFET 1 Spec**
>
> Model: NTBLS0D7N06C
>
> Datasheet:
> https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108141230_onsemi-NTBLS0D7N06C_C903210.pdf
>
> Rds(on): 0.75 mΩ

> - **MOSFET 2 Spec**
>
> Model: IRFP1405PbF
>
> Datasheet:
> https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1806051242_Infineon-Technologies-IRFP1405PBF_C212022.pdf
>
> Rds(on): 5.3 mΩ

I made a prototyping board using **MOSFET2**. (below)

[image]

I installed a heat sink, but the heat is worse than I thought, so I'm considering a bigger heat sink.

- **Schematic diagram**

[image]

- **View of assembled**

[image]

- **Two SMPS for feeding power to LED**

[image]

---

I learned that Rds(on) levels must be low to reduce heat.

I'm comparing and exploring the core element, MOSFET.

And I found a MOSFET that looked good. (**MOSFET 1**)

---

The power dissipation of **MOSFET 1** is as follows.

```
I = 50 A
R = 0.75 mΩ
V = 37.5 mV
W = 1.875 W
```

The power dissipation of **MOSFET 2** is as follows.

```
I = 50 A
R = 5.3 mΩ
V = 265 mV
W = 13.25 W
```

Calculating the power dissipation ratio of the two MOSFETsis about 7 times.

Even if Rds(on) is increased due to the increase in the junction temperature, I think the dissipation can be reduced a lot compared to **MOSFET 2**.

I'm very happy now, but I can't believe it's so magical.

---

I'd like to ask everyone to confirm if what I understood is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: The key thing is how you're driving the MOSFET gates and whether you're getting enough voltage fast enough. Show us the schematic or it's very hard to give any advice.

Comment: You should also consider a higher voltage LED if you can, the lower current for the same power makes switching easier with lower losses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I updated this article.
Can you confirm again for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of just plucking figures like Rds(on) from datasheets because they vary a lot according to factors like Vgs and temperature. If you look at the datasheet for your MOSFET 2 you'll see the graph of Id vs Vds and I've put an orange circle where you'll be operating as the junction temperature gets up towards its maximum:

[image]

As you can see, you can expect a Vds of about 450 mV and hence a power dissipation of around 22.5 W, nearly twice what you've calculated. Look at the same graph for MOSFET 1 to see the difference it will make.

Comment: But this is for the junction temperature of around 175°C. Since the MOSFETs look well-cooled, the dissipation will not hit that levels.

Comment: @RohatKılıç True, but the point is that you need to compare the graphs between the two devices to see the difference

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I should've missed the main point.

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for teaching about graph of Id vs Vds.
It seems that the change in Vds due to Id current is also important.

Answer (score 0):

Rds(on) is quite important but, how the MOSFETs are driven is also important.

I see that you are using a gate drive chip. That chip looks a bit overkill to me because its main purpose is to drive half- or full-bridge arrangements where bootstrapping and dead times are required. But if it's working and if you are happy then leave it.

One other thing I'd like to say is that when you parallel two MOSFETs, even if they are identical, it's always good to have separate gate stopper resistors to prevent oscillations which may lead to horrible things. I see that you tied the gates directly to LED GL LO lane, so it would be better if you use series resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xshS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of the resistances are determined by,

- driving capability (i.e. peak driving current) of the driver chip,
- and driving (PWM or whatever) frequency.

When the MOSFET is off and the gate pulse signal is applied, due to the empty input capacitance (basically a short circuit) of the MOSFET, a high current will flow through the drive output of the driver chip for a very short time. We don't want that current to exceed the peak drive capability of the driver chip because this will happen repetitively. From the datasheet, the peak drive capability is given as 2A and the datasheet doesn't tell us anything about current limitation. Since the gate pulse signal is 12V and two MOSFETs are driven, a series resistance of at least 12 Ohms for each MOSFET will be good (12V/12Ohms for each MOSFET).

Since this gate resistor (R) and Ciss (input capacitance) of the MOSFET form a low-pass filter, the cut-off frequency (fc) of this filter should be way beyond the driving frequency:

$$
f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi R\ C_{iss}} >> f_{sw}
$$

The Ciss of the MOSFET is given as 5.6nF. I don't know what driving frequency you use in your design. So calculate a possible R and make sure it's higher than or equal to 12 Ohms.

Example: If the driving frequency (fsw) is 500 Hz then we can select the cutoff frequency as 50kHz (not to lose sharp edges). So a possible gate resistor can be calculated as 560R. Even 100R will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My driving frequency is 1KHz.
Now, I can calculate the value of resistor what you say because of you.
Thanks for teaching me about very important thing.

Comment: @laco22 you can calculate but 100R is still good for even 1 kHz.